# Credentials for trailhead playground

Tags: trailhead

Recently trailhead has introduced a very handy playground org for the tasks. Really I have no issue with it even I don't really know my user name and password for that playground org.

However, for this trail: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/reports_dashboards/reports_dashboards_appexchange I need to install a managed package into the target org which requires user login. But I still can't find my credential for that org... How can I walk around this issue?

Comment: FYI, you still don't need your credentials. just copy the part after the domain name on top of the URL for your playground, and it'll auto-sign-in for you. I recently went through this with a superbadge install (still working on it), and came up with the following link: https://na35.salesforce.com/packagingSetupUI/ipLanding.app?apvId=04t36000000g5yC ... You just need to use your domain name + the package install link path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Welcome tab there is link to get the credentials which you can use to get credentials.

Long story short Go to your user > Confirm your email is correct and click on Reset password link and you will get the Rest password link where you can reset the password.

[Details Step by Step](https://force.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/2659738-how-to-get-a-password-for-my-trailhead-playground?b_id=13478)

Answer (score 3):

couple of options i can think of

- Reset your password after you launch the playground
- open the unmanaged package and change the org name in the url to direct it to your playground

Comment: +1 Second option is my preferred method. Why manage passwords when the trailhead does it for me?